# I have two question about "stock up" & "dress shirts"

Tags: word-meaning, phrasal-verbs

> NEW YORK — Perry Ellis is not a brand that makes men nervous or causes them to titter. Even if a work-a-day guy doesn’t wear Perry Ellis clothes, he probably recognizes the name from those times he has wandered through a department store looking to **stock up** on dress shirts. Perry Ellis is not niche; it is mass. And its creative director, Michael Maccari designed a spring 2016 collection that was welcoming to a wide swath of men. Board shorts, crewneck sweaters, lean — but not tight — suits. Rich colors but nothing too psychedelic.

It is saying **dress shirts** , and it looks like as if the word *dress** acts as an adjective. What does the writer really mean by saying dress shirts?

Is **stock up** here s noun?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

"Stock up" is a set term meaning to "increase the quantity of an item you have."

So, if it's winter and you won't be able to get to the grocery store because there's a major snow storm coming, you would "stock up" on food and other supplies so that you wouldn't starve when you couldn't go out.

In this case, a man who is starting a new job (as an example) may "stock up" on essential items like dress shirts as he will likely need at least five to get through the work week.

A "Dress shirt" is (usually) a men's business shirt.

It's usually long-sleeved, button-up with a collar and often worn with a tie, though you can have a "Short-sleeved dress shirt":

[image: A Dress shirt]